# Convert List<TypeA> to Map<TypeA, List<TypeB>> using Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
class  A {
    private B b;
}
```

```
Map<A, List<B>> bListMap = new HashMap<>();

        aList.forEach(
                a-> {
                    
                    List<B> bList =
                            aList.stream().filter(aVal -> a.getUuid().equals(aVal.getUuid()))
                                          .map(A::getB)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    bListMap.put(a, bList);
                });
```

For some reason, I am getting same record multiple times in bList.

What am I doing wrong?

**Side Note:**
Query Result:
A.id, A.name, b.id, b.name

Mapping between Table A and B is one to many

Comment: If an instance of A contains a single B instance, why do you need to map a `List<B>` for each `A` instance?

Comment: If I got you right, you just want to put all elements from `listA` into a `Map` that maps each `A` element to its `B` field? Just do `listA.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Functions.identity(), a -> a.b))` then, done.

Comment: Not really, the problem here is I am getting a database result where technically the mapping between A and B is one to many. But, as I am using stored procedure, I am not able to get it that way. Instead, I'm getting each record manually and creating the structure I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're iterating each element in `aList` and collecting list of B from the elements `aList` who have the same `uuid`.

Let say 2 of the 5 elements in `aList` has the same uuid (say `uuid1`) but different B. Say one has `B1` and another has `B2`. In this segment:

```
aList.forEach(
            a-> {
                
                List<B> bList =
                        aList.stream().filter(aVal -> a.getUuid().equals(aVal.getUuid()))
                                      .map(A::getB)
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
                bListMap.put(a, bList);
            });
```

You are trying to iterate through each `A` in aList. So, you'll iterate for `uuid1` two times and set the list `bList` two times in the `bListMap`, because your key is nothing but the `A` itself. As a result, as they are different object instances, their identity is different, and using them as a key will lead to different map entry. That is why you'll get:

```
{
    A1(with uuid1) : bList1,
    A2(with uuid1) : bList1
}
```

What you can do is, take a list of distinct uuid's of A from `aList`. And `forEach` uuids, do what you're doing earlier. As we're looking at A with a `uuid` just once, there'll be no duplicate occurance for key `A` and it's corresponding list `bList` in the final `bListMap`.
Let's look at the changed implementation that we've discussed just now:

```
List<A> objAWithDistinctUuid = aList.stream()
            .filter(distinctByKey(A::getUuid))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

objAWithDistinctUuid.stream().forEach(
            a -> {
                List<B> bList =
                        aList.stream().filter(aVal -> a.getUuid().equals(aVal.getUuid()))
                                .map(A::getB)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                bListMap.put(a, bList);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

`aList.stream().filter(aVal -> a.getUuid().equals(aVal.getUuid()))` basically selects all *A* instances in that list which match the current instance's uuid. If multiple instances have the same uuid you'll select multiple Bs. And if `A` doesn't have a proper `equals()` and `hashCode()` or they aren't using `uuid` only, you'll use each single instance of A as a map key - hence getting the "same list of Bs" twice.

Example: assume you get the following A and B id's and map them according to your `class  A`:

```
| A uuid | A instance | B id |
------------------------------
​| 1      | 0xCAFEBABE | 1    |
| 1      | 0x0BADBEEF | 2    |
```

Now your loop will collect B id's 1 and 2 for each of those A's but since they don't have the instance id (internally managed by the JVM, based on memory address), you'll get the following map:

```
{ 
  A(1, 0xCAFEBABE)=[B(1), B(2)],
  A(1, 0x0BADBEEF)=[B(1), B(2)]
}
```

> How to fix this, given "Query Result: A.id, A.name, b.id, b.name" ?

Have a look at `Map.computeIfAbsent()` which allows you to create a list if it's missing, return the new or existing map and then chain the add of the B.

Something like (pseudo code here):

```
Map<Integer, A> aMap = ...

for(resultSet) {
   A a = aMap.computeIfAbsent(resultSet.aId, aId -> new A(aId, resultSet.aName));
   aToBMmap.computeIfAbsent( a, k -> new ArrayList<>())
       .add(new B(resultSet.bId, resultSet.bName));
)
```

Comment: The part I find weird is I am getting it like
```
{ 
      A(1, 0xCAFEBABE)=[B(1), B(1)]
    }
```

Comment: @Jammy - that's basically a representation of the classes (`type(values)`) and the `key=value` relation.